# Set notation for a list of intervals?

Tags: notation

I am trying to describe a list of time intervals in set notation.

Specifically, say I have a set t* of all times t that make function f(t) = J. Formally, I think this is `t* = {t|f(t) = J}`.

I then want the set T* of consecutive times (i.e., intervals) in t* for which f(t) < J. Would this be something like follows: `T* = {[t*_i,t*_j]|j = i + 1 & f((t*_i,t*_j)/2) < J}` ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps$$T^*=\{\,[a,b]\mid f(a)=f(b)=J\land  \forall x\in(a,b)\colon f(x)<J\,\} $$?